# Predefined Dialog templates in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, templates, dialog

In VB.NET is there a library of template dialogs I can use?  It's easy to create a custom dialog and inherit from that, but it seems like there would be some templates for that sort of thing.

I just need something simple like Save/Cancel, Yes/No, etc.

Edit: MessageBox is not quite enough, because I want to add drop-down menus, listboxes, grids, etc.  If I had a dialog form where I could ask for some pre-defined buttons, each of which returned a modal result and closed the form, then I could add those controls and the buttons would already be there.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't use the MessageBox class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create your own template? I've done that with several types of forms, not just dialogs. It is a great way to give yourself a jump-start.

Create your basic dialog, keeping it as generic as possible, then save it as a template.

Here is an article that will help you:

http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/soa/Save-time-with-Visual-Studio-2005-project-templates/0,339028399,339285540,00.htm

And:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing that and I agree it's easy.  I was just wondering if there was a generic template out there.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: If all you are looking for are simple things like yes/no, ok/cancel, you should really consider just using the built in functionality of the MessageBox (msgbox) class.

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with the MessageBox class that makes you refuse to use it.

Comment: Please see my comment in the original post

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something more than what can be provided by MsgBox?

```
MsgBox("Do you want to see this message?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Respond")
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, he did say VB.NET, oh well. Either way, these should work for him.

Answer (score 0):

Are you unable to use the [MessageBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335422(VS.71).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's MessageBox (shorthand *MsgBox* in VB.Net) and also the windows common dialogs like Open File, Save File, Print, ColorPicker, etc.

However, none of those really qualify as templates.

I can sympathize with wanting a better message box from time to time.  You might try code project: I'll bet you'll see a dozen...